# Multiple ELMAH Databases

Tags: elmah

We use ELMAH for logging, and what we would ideally like to do is customize our ELMAH connection strings so that each *environment* (dev, uat, qa, production) goes to a separate ELMAH log. (There are compelling reasons to do this which have to do with our business process and the nature of our applications.)

I've been unable to determine, by scouring the documentation and googling madly, whether or not the database used by ELMAH *must* be named "ELMAH", or if I can customize it to be "dev", "qa", "uat", and "prod" (appropriate to the environment we're deploying to).

Can someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write *database*, you don't really say anything about which database your are using.

That being set, ELMAH logging to databases are based on connection strings in web.config. This means that you can have individual connection strings for each environment. You can "swap" these in by using [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks!